# Estimating weights for dimensions of vectors in similarity-calculations in vector-spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, correlation

My problem can be stated as follows:

I have a vector space in which vectors live, these vectors reflect *events* in real life, and their components reflect *characteristics of these events*. What I want to do is find a distance function which measures *similarity between events*. I could simply use euclidean distance, but in my particular problem, different dimensions 'matter more' in comparing events with each other (i.e. they are more *salient*).

An event is for example denoted by a vector $[2, 5, 11, 82, 23]$, an outcome is denoted by another vector in which the first two components refer to classes (1-8 possibilities for the first element, and 1-3 possibilities for the second element), and the third refers to a continuous value, i.e. $[8, 2, 24.5]$.

So, I have many millions of such event vectors (in reality, the event vectors have much more components) and corresponding 'outcome vectors'.

First question: **how can I somehow generate a distance function to compare event vectors, in which different dimensions have different weights?**

Now, to make things even more difficult: what if two dimensions with a very low weight individually do not matter much, but if they *both* have unusual values (for example, they both have low values, or they both have high values, or one high and one low - this can differ among pairs of dimensions), these dimensions are *extremely significant*.

So, in other words, using my same example; let's say that the fourth and fifth component of my event vector 'do not really matter'; when comparing different event vectors with the distance function I am trying to find (see first question), their values only have a very small impact on the calculated distance between two event vectors (the similarity of two events). However, if they both have a certain type of value, they matter *much more* than the three preceding dimensions. I was thinking about creating a matrix of correlation values for every pair of dimensions, and also calculate a weight for each pair.

**If my question is still unclear, then yet in other words:**

I have a multi-dimensional vector space with many millions of 'event vectors' $[c_1, c_2, c_3 ... c_i]$. All of them have a respective outcome vector which has much less dimensions: $[o_1, o_2, o_3]$. In my particular problem, $o_1$ and $o_2$ correspond to class indices (with 8 and 3 classes respectively) and $o_3$ is a continuous number. What I want to do is to construct a distance function which measures the *similarity* between events. Each dimension should be weighted differently in the distance function. So it could be that if the values of the $c_1$ - components of two vectors are very close to each other, these events are likely to be very similar, and $c_2 ... c_i$ matter much less. What approach should I take to calculate a distance function which measures similarity on such way? It could also be that $o_1, o_2, o_3$ have different degrees in how much they distinct different outcomes.

In my particular problem, it happens that two components, $c_j$ and $c_k$ have a very low weight in the distance function (they can almost be neglected when comparing two vectors with each other, their values are very insignificant). However, if they *both* have a certain type of value (i.e. they both have very low values; both have very high values; or one has a low, and one has a high value - this depends on which pair of dimensions we are considering) they are *extremely significant*. So, if normally their individual values almost would not matter at all, if they *both* have a certain type of value occurring together, their weight should be much higher than the highest individual dimension!

Comment: You obviously have some intuition for which values of $c$ are similar to which other values of $c$, but how do you propose to make that information available to the algorithm? Is it somehow encoded in $o$?

Comment: Do you mean how vector components are similar to other components within the same vector (so, in different dimensions), so, how $c_1$ is for example similar to $c_2$? I don't have intuition on that. How $c_1$'s are similar among groups of similar vectors (with the same outcome vectors) I proposed modeling by finding the mean of every $c_i$ for all vectors with a corresponding same $o$, and then estimating the variance (using MLE) of these means.

Comment: No but I think you let slip the answer when you said "...groups of similar vectors (with the same outcome vectors)..."

Comment: Presumably the question of similarity is not one you need worry about with respect to vectors already in your data set? You have the outcome vectors already so you know exactly which subsets of input vectors from the data set give rise to the same outcome. Which suggests to me that you are looking for a predictive model for outcome given an arbitrary input vector.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! Actually, I am really looking for a way to measure the similarity (or distance between vectors in a space). I came up with the 'outcome vectors' myself as a temporarily tool to find the weights for the 'real similarity function', the outcome vectors are merely a tool to get the weights, for the rest I don't need them, and I don't really need to predict them, they are also not very accurate.

Comment: My comments are something less than "thoughts". I have merely been trying to establish what you actually want. But without success I'm afraid—now I find myself returning to my first question.